# Eraser Tool Malfunction on Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

The result of the eraser tool on my Adobe Illustrator CC keeps popping back up even though I have already erased it.

I'm a beginner on Illustrator, so I do not know how to work it well, though it is quite similar to Photoshop, I don't know how to use several things in this application.

Comment: Sorry but you should go back and learn the basics of illustrator first. We're not a software tutorial forum, the questions should be focused on design. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Have you tried selecting the object first then using the eraser?

Answer (score 2):

The Eraser tool won't erase images, text, symbols, graphs, or gradient meshes. The preview, whilst your mouse button is still held down *will* preview these objects being erased, but when you release the mouse they will actually remain intact.

The Eraser tool will erase *any* valid object if there is no selection. If you have any objects selected though it will only erase those *selected objects*. Again, it *will* preview *any* objects being erased whilst your mouse button is still held down, even if those objects aren't really being erased. It's a bit of a stupid implementation but hey, what can we do.

- [**Adobe Illustrator blog: Mysteries of the Eraser Tool — Revealed!**](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/2009/04/mysteries_of_the_eraser_tool_r.html)